# Dropdown menu error?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I recently made a vertical dropdown menu using CSS3. I'm having a problem though: The first subcategory will show on hover, but the second is only supposed to show when you move onto the first nested ul. You can view the following code in action at [Mac-Resources](http://www.mac-resources.net/%20%22Mac-Resources). The following is my nav structure:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Aktuelles</a>
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Termine</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Archiv</li></a>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Schule in Aktion</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>hEImun</a>
                <ul>    
                    <li><a href="#"><span></span>What is MUN?</li></a>
                    <li><a href="#"><span></span>What is hEImun?</li></a>
                    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Schedule</li></a>
                    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Accomodations</li></a>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>AGs, AGs, AGs</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Begabtenf&ouml;rderung</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Wettbewerbe</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Theater</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Milchbar</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Oberstufe</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Compassion</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>BOGY</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Sport</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Unterrichtsprojekte</li></a>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Unterrichtsangebot</a>
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Profile</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Der Bilinguale Zug</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Ganztageszug</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Methodencurriculum</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Interne Regelungen</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Grundschule</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Englisch-Zertifikate</li></a>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>P&auml;dagogik</a>
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Bausteine</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Soziales Lernen</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Beratungsm&ouml;glichkeiten am E.I.</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Ganzheitliche Lernberatung</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Compassion</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Suchtprophylaxe</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Anti-Gewaltprojekte</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>P&auml;dagogische Tage und Vortr&auml;ge</li></a>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>&Uuml;ber uns</a>
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Unsere Idee von Schule</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Leitbild und Qualit&auml;t</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Schulleitung und Kollegium</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Qualit&auml;tsentwicklung</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Aufnahme am E.I.</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Elternbeitr&auml;ge</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Mitwirkung der Eltern</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Mitwirkung der Sch&uuml;ler</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Gremien</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Freundeskreis</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Milchbar</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Geschichte</li></a>
            <li><a href="#"><span></span>Die Schulgr&uuml;nderin</li></a>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Schulweb</li></a>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>E.I. unterwegs</li></a>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS markup:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}

nav a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding: 7px;
    }

nav a:hover {
    background: #fcc74b;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    }

nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    top:0;
    display: none;
    }

nav ul ul li {
    width: 200px;
    background: #99CC33;
    }

nav ul ul li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    }

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

nav span {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    }

nav a:hover span {
    background: #003399;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your html code. problem in `</li></a>` must fix to `</a></li>`

```
<li><a href="#"><span></span>Termine</li></a>
```

TO

```
<li><a href="#"><span></span>Termine</a></li>
```

after that fix some css style for position of level2 menu and level3 menu. [see demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/bDJxk/)

I change the position of menu leve2:

```
nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top:0;
    display: none;
}
```

And add some style for menu level3

```
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top:0;
    display: none;
}
```

Hide menu level3 when hover menu level1

```
nav ul li:hover ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

but display it when hover menu level2:

```
nav ul li ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

[see demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/bDJxk/)